# DISM how to apply a change to all image indexes

Tags: windows-server-2012, disk-image, windows-server, dism

This one has been in my head since long time now and I can't formulate the right question on google to find myself an answer so I'll give it a try here.

It's about DISM and WIM Files (Windows Imaging Format)

My Install.Wim has for indexes :

```
1 Windows Server 2012 R2 SERVERSTANDARDCORE
2 Windows Server 2012 R2 SERVERSTANDARD
3 Windows Server 2012 R2 SERVERDATACENTERCORE
4 Windows Server 2012 R2 SERVERDATACENTER
```

What if I want to apply a change (adding a patch, adding a file, install a windows feature) to all 4 indexes at the same time ?

I currently mount each index at the time, apply my changes, commit my changes and then dismount the image and start over with the next index.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: nope, there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do it in all indexes...

But you can make a trick based on : ( from [Tarak Bhavsar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683600/how-can-i-know-total-number-of-index-available-in-a-windows-index-wim-file-using) )

```
 @echo off

 if exist %TEMP%\scm (RD %TEMP%\scm /S /Q)
 md %TEMP%\scm

 for /L %%A IN (1, 1, 25) Do (

 dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:%%A > %TEMP%\scm\%%A.txt
 timeout 0 >nul
 Find /i "Error:" "%Temp%\scm\%%A.TXT" > nul && (
      set "Index=%%A"
        goto:next
 ) 
 )

 exit/b

 :next
 set /A Ti = %Index% - 1
 ECHO There are %Ti% number of indexes in the image.

 pause
```

Hope this will help you and others !!